# What causes Mirth to send an "RST" reset command to an outbound IP and port?

Tags: mirth

We have a Mirth system running and one channel seems to get disconnected every few hours.  The vendor indicated that it is getting these errors:
9:49:05AM 05/18/21 - THE REAL-TIME CONNECTION WAS BROKEN BY ENGINE
9:49:07AM 05/18/21 - WAITING FOR CONNECTION TO idxhost
9:49:07AM 05/18/21 - AN ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED WITH THE REAL-TIME CONNECTION
ERROR ACCEPTING CONNECTION

And Mirth is sending "rst" commands to reset the connection.
What would cause the reset to be sent and why would the connection be broken but only for a certain port?
The IP with other ports works fine for the same vendor and we have tried to change the port but still get the disconnects.   The port was originally 3964 and is now 3960 but still has the same weird issue.

Comment: Found out that we had a response timeout of 5000 but the responses were sometimes taking up to 8 seconds.   Increased the response timeout to 20000 to see if that resolves the issue.  I will know in a few days.

Comment: The response timeout had no affect on the connection issues.